# Finding cluster number based on distance & max element count

Tags: clustering, algorithms, k-means, spatial, k-medoids

Given two constraints:

- The maximum distance *d* an element can lie from a cluster centroid (or medoid)
- The maximum number of elements *n* in one cluster

Is it possible to find the minimum number of clusters which would contain all elements in a region?

One brute-force approach would be to place each element in its own cluster and methodically decreasing the number of clusters, but I feel like there has to be a more graceful solution.

I'm rather new to cluster analysis, so any references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware that such problems can easily be np-hard. Then finding the *minimum* may be infeasible. You may still be able to find a good approximation.

In your case, the problem encompasses the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). All possible clusters that do not violate your constraints form the sets, and finding the minimum then is the set cover problem, which is known to be np-hard.

Comment: In this case, I want to use these two initial conditions to approximate a minimum value for 'k' in a k-means or k-medoids algorithm. You suggest first finding all possible clusters, then computing the minimum number a la set cover problem. For your approach, what would be the best clustering method to do so?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to do that. This is just the outline of a proof that your problem is **np-hard**, so you may want to relax the constraints and search for an approximation. Just like k-means does: **finding the true minimum is too expensive**.

Comment: Ended up using a heuristic algorithm that checks distance and max cluster elements after each k-means cycle. It's computationally expensive, but gets the job done for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you can express your constraints as linear ones, there is an effective way to solve your problems, at least with a $k$-means objective.

For instance, your second constraint (enforcing a maximum number of elements in a cluster) can be expressed linearly, and then you can optimize the $k$-means energy by calling a LP-solver with your constraints. This is basically what is done in [*Constrained K-Means Clustering*](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69796/tr-2000-65.pdf). Authors prove that it converges monotically toward a local minimum (alike the (standard) Lloyds-heuristic).

Comment: k-means will usually not find the global minimum. It's not that easy to solve things exactly and efficiently, as k-means already is NP-hard. Also, k-means needs to know k beforehand, he wants to minimize the number of clusters.

Comment: Yes, k-means is NP-hard. But, keep in mind, that it is a result for solving the minimization in general. Some cases can be solved exactly in polynomial-time, for instance the [1D-case](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2485v2.pdf), [under stability conditions](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/Papers/clustering-IPL.pdf), or can be [approximated arbitrarily well with PTAS on coresets](http://sarielhp.org/p/03/kcoreset/kcoreset.pdf).